# To Gist or not to Gist

Tags: discussion, community-guidelines

Regarding the answer here: [How can I programmatically add a rendering to all of my content items?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-i-programmatically-add-a-rendering-to-all-of-my-content-items)

Personally; I would prefer the Gist reference in the answer to actually be embedded into the post, optionally with a link to the source. One of the basic ideas of Stack Exchange sites is; it puts the question and the full complete (best) answer right next to each other and ideally the answer is comprehensive.

It's absolutely fine, of course, to then add links to additional online resources (in this case, the API guide).

*EDIT*

I've proposed the edit. We're a little short on peer reviewers right now (need 500 rep), but pretty soon stuff like this will be trivial for us to manage ourselves :-)

[image: Suggested edit]

Comment: I totally agree with you Mark.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I agree. The code should be added to the answer.

There is not many things that are more frustrating that finding an answer to a problem with link which is not working.

Answer (score 6):

I agree, hence my comment. Answers should be as comprehensive as sensibly possible. Not all links are created equal and are easily broken.

I gave the opportunity for the self-edit but agree it needs to be updated.